# Long date format to short date format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I want to convert long date format like Sat Dec 13 2014 06:00:00 GMT+0600 to 2014-12-13 yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
<script>
function myDate(val)
 {

var now = new Date("<?php echo $Cnextdue;?>");
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 30*val);

document.getElementById("txtnextdue").value=now;
}
</script>
```

now variable print in text box as "Sat Dec 13 2014 06:00:00 GMT+0600"

I want to make as 2014-12-13

Comment: If you are trying to do this in JavaScript, you might want to think about using the DateJs library.  It has a lot of nice tools for working with dates.  - https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

Answer (score 2):

Use following.

```js
function getDateFormatted(inputdate) {
  var k = inputdate;
  var dt = new Date(k);
  var yr = dt.getYear() + 1900;
  var mn = dt.getMonth() + 1;
  return yr + "-" + mn + "-" + dt.getDate();

}
alert(getDateFormatted("Sat Dec 13 2014 06:00:00 GMT+0600"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by yourself.

But I would suggest you to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), so you have more flexibility to change the format in the future if you want.

Using it is as simple as:

```
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```